# Grouping by multiple fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

This is my document structure:

```
{
    "ip_address" : "192.168.133.12",
    "timestamp" : "2014-08-28T06:41:24",
    "response" : 400,
    "uri" : {
        "term" : "Something",
        "page" : "10",
        "category" : "category 10"
    }
}
```

If I want to do groupby on a single field 'response' I will do it as follows:

```
db.collName.aggregate({ $group : {_id : "$response", total : { $sum : 1 }} });
```

How do I group by 2 or say 3 fields? Is it possible to groupby multiple fields, so that they form a aggregate with similar values?

I mean something like this:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "responseValue" + "ip_addressValue",
            "totaling" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes possible, you could do something like below

```
db.collName.aggregate({ $group : 
 {
   "_id" : {"response":"$response", "ip_address":"$ip_address"}, 
   total : { $sum : 1 }
 } 
});
```

Comment: hmm sounds logical, but why am I getting "Syntax Error: Unexpected token :"??

Comment: @vmr Use braces `{  }`, not brackets `[ ]` in the `_id` definition.